# Traduction de « het begint te kriebelen», littéralement « ça commence à picoter »

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, néerlandais

Il y a un joli mot néerlandais pour dire qu’on s’éprend de quelque chose de nouveau. Il se traduit littéralement par « picoter ». Voici une esquisse qui montre son sens.

Comme déjà dit, le mot est souvent utilisé quand on s’engouait d’un sujet autrefois. Quelqu’un cesse de pratiquer un métier où un passe-temps, parce qu’il n’a plus envie de l’exercer. Quelques mois ou années plus tard, le gré de le faire revient. Alors ce divertissement ou travail commence à « picoter ».

Ce mot ne s’accompagne guère avec un objet. On dit « ça commence à picoter » pour dire « la volonté de reprendre cette besogne se relève dans moi. » C’est le locuteur qui est saisi par l’envie, on n’emploie pas ce mot pour décrire les souhaits d’autrui.

Dernièrement, l’envie est assez légère, (ce qui ressort déjà un peu de cette tournure). L’envie peut s’enforcir ou s’affaiblir plus tard. Le mot ne sous-entend pas qu’on se plie au gré. On peut également choisir de l’oublier et de prolonger sa vie sans ce  passe-temps / boulot d’autrefois.

Comment: Personne n'a encore corrigé cette question. Qui peut le faire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quelqu’un dans cette situation peut dire que quelque chose le [démange](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9manger).

> Je rachèterai bien un piano. Depuis quelques mois, ça me démange à nouveau.

Cependant, l’expression ne s’emploie pas que pour des interruptions longues.

> Depuis quinze jours que je n’ai pas couru, ça me démange un peu.